# R function to sum value for certain age for each year

Tags: r

I would like to sum BEFO ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfgr4.png)) when age is between 0 et 18 and between 64 and 120 (so 2 different group). It has to be repeated for each year (time between 2008 and 2017).

I tried and success to do it step by step but not with a function or loop so I would like a better way than mine.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi i dont have any exeample to give, i tried some but it was probably far from the target.

Comment: Hello. You can make an example. Just take a sample of your data frame (as shown in the picture you attached...something like `dput(head(df))` will produce a reproducible example) or create a toy example and share it. In any case you must have an example along with expected output. Also please make sure to also add your attempts that failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use `dplyr` and assuming you have successfully loaded the data set into a data.frame named `df`, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(
    year,
    age_group = ifelse(age <= 18, '0 - 18', ifelse(age >= 64, '64 - 120', '19 - 63'))
  ) %>% summarise(BEFO=sum(BEFO))
```

The challenge is creating a sufficient label for group. You can do this in a separate `mutate` call, or on-the-fly in the `group_by` as I have done here. If you do so separately, it becomes more readable:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(agegroup = c(0, 18, 64, 121), right=FALSE, labels=c('0-18','19-63','64-120'))) %>%
  group_by(agegroup, year) %>%
  summarise(BEFO=sum(BEFO))
```

(and sorry for using two different methods for cutting the age groups into different bins)